# Query condition based on many for one-to-may relationship

Tags: android, android-room

Based on https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#java

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @PrimaryKey public long userId;
    public String name;
    public int age;
}

@Entity
public class Playlist {
    @PrimaryKey public long playlistId;
    public long userCreatorId;
    public String playlistName;
}

public class UserWithPlaylists {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    public List<Playlist> playlists;
}
```

---

To query **all** `UserWithPlaylists`, we can simply

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylists();
```

---

But, what if we want to query `UserWithPlaylists` with `Playlist`.`name` as condition?

The following is the incorrect way. But, what is the correct way to do so?

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE ???")
public List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylists();
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data?hl=en#java

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM User AS u Join Playlist as p on u.userId = p.userCreatorId where p.playlistName like :playListName")
List<UserWithPlaylists> getUsersWithPlaylistsByPlayListName(String playListName);
```

you can call value of parameter use ":$(parameter name)" in your query, and use 'join' keyword to matching user table and playlist table.

```
public class UserWithPlaylists {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Relation(
         parentColumn = "userId",
         entityColumn = "userCreatorId"
    )
    public List<Playlist> playlists;
}
```

you can infer 'User.userId' and 'Playlist.userCreatorId' are consistent here.

Answer (score 0):

It's a common request, but there is no built-in decision for that.
There are several registered issues, here is [one of them](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65509934) dated by 2017 year, but there is still no proper decision for it.

The main point that @Relation (under the hood at the moment) is equivalent to two separate queries, and you don't have any way to set condition on the second query (you write query just for the first one). Maybe that would be changed in the later versions.

Reply on [another issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/163617139) might be useful:

> @Relation is a convenience feature and does not support custom ordering or WHERE statements in the query that fetches the child relation. Doing 2 queries in a @Transaction method is the right approach, in essence that is exactly what @Relation does, it queries for all Parent rows, then queries for all the Child rows and then when building your POJO containing the @Relation field it adds the Child instances to the respective Parent based on what was defined as parent & entity column ids. The reason @Relation is limited is because it can lead to the developer fetching a whole tree of tables and relations when they might only want to present/need one or two layers at a time.

As a workaround, you can write your own query without @Relation, with tables' joins, to set there needed condition. But to get result similar to `UserWithPlaylists` you have to do it manually. Or to be satisfied with result structure like that:

```
public class UserWithPlaylists {
    @Embedded public User user;
    @Embedded public Playlist playlist;  // <--- not list, just a single value
}
```